# How to test a call to external api in Spring Boot

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, testing, mockito

I have a method in the service class that uses an external wrapper to call the slack api. The wrapper I'm using is this [one](https://github.com/seratch/jslack) if it makes any difference. This is how I'm using the wrapper,

```
//This is the method in my service class
public String sendMess(SlackObj obj) {
    //SlackObj contains the channel url, channel name and the message
    //build the payload from the SlackObj
    //Slack is the name of the wrapper's class that I'm using
    Slack slack = Slack.getInstance();
    //slack.send is the method that sends the message to slack
    WebhookResponse res = slack.send(url, payload);
    //other logic
}

//This is what I've tried
@Test
public void slackSendMessageTest(){
    //build the slack obj and payload
    //build the mock WebhookResponse
    Slack slackMock = mock(Slack.class)
    when(slackMock.send(channelUrl, payload)).thenReturn(mockWebHookRes);
    assertEquals("SUCCESS", testService.sendMessage(testSlackObj);
}
```

I am trying to write some tests for this method, so my question is, how would i test it without having the message sent every time I run the test?  I believe the cause of this is because slack itself is not mocked and I have no idea as how to inject the mock into the mocked service class.

I am open to refactoring the service class if it helps with the testing. Any suggestions and recommendation is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to have to find a way to mock `Slack`, which appears to be a singleton, unfortunately.

Here's what I would do:

**1) Make `Slack` available as a bean that can be autowired:**

```
@Configuration
public class SlackConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Slack slack() {
        return Slack.getInstance();
    }
}
```

**2) Change your class to take an injected `Slack`:**

Note that I am totally guessing on the name here, as you just show the method. You would inject the `Slack` object you turned into a `@Bean` above, and not use `Slack.getInstance()` directly anywhere else.

```
@Component
public class SlackService {
    private final Slack slack;

    @Autowired
    public SlackService(final Slack slack) {
        this.slack = slack;
    }

    public String sendMessage(final Object message) {
        final WebhookResponse res = slack.send(url, payload);
        // etc
    }
}
```

**3) Mock the `Slack` object and pass it to your `SlackService` in test:**

This allows you to mock out the implementation of `Slack`, so you can alter its behavior. I won't go into mocking in detail.

```
public class SlacServiceTest {
    private final Slack slack = mock(Slack.class);
    private final SlackService serviceUnderTest = new SlackService(slack);

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        // TODO: set mock responses here
        // Given... when... then...
    }

}
```